# How to send email when order status is updated ? prestashop

Tags: prestashop

```
              foreach($order_to_convert as $odr_id)  {
                    $objOrder = new Order($odr_id);
                    $history = new OrderHistory();
                    $history->id_order = (int)$objOrder->id;
                    //$history->changeIdOrderState((int)$sts_id, (int)($objOrder->id));
                    //$history->add(true);
                    $history->addWithemail(true);
                    //$history->save();
             }
```

I have used above code to update order status & send email to customers but due to performance issue i have removed the code above & used query to perform the same. but i am not able to send email to customers.

Is their any way to send customer email when the order status is updated ?

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63469396/how-to-send-email-programatically-prestashop Regards

Comment: In some servers *Mail::Send* does not work. Just try a simple PHP *mail* function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.