# How to Send email programatically Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

Hello i am trying to send email in prestashop in module
but its not working.

Is their any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check `Mail` class and `Send` method.

Example:

```
Mail::Send(
    (int) $this->context->language->id,
    $this->getTemplate(),
    $this->getSubject(),
    $this->getTemplateVars(),
    $this->getTo(),
    $this->getToName(),
    $this->getFrom(),
    $this->getFromName(),
    $this->getFileAttachment(),
    $this->isModeSmtp(),
    $this->getTemplatePath(),
    $this->isDie(),
    (int) $this->context->shop->id,
    $this->getBcc(),
    $this->getReplyTo()
);
```

You have more examples in entire system. Just search for "Mail::Send" in code.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer can you please edit the answer with the static values ?